# How to capture list of csv files with complicated pattern by system.file()?

Tags: r, regex, csv

I have list of csv files that needed to used in my R package as external data. I used `system.file()` let these csv files available for my package vignette code. I quickly looked into regexp features of R in SO, get initial idea to do this. However, my function is not effective for me and I got error instead, because it did not capture pattern that appeared in inst/extdata directory, so some csv file is missing in my output. I expect all csv files can be captured by `system.file()` and printed out on console or stored in object. Can any one point me how to fix issue in `getExtDat` ? How can I capture all csv files in `inst/extdata` with matched pattern and print them out in R session ? Any efficient way to deal with csv files with complicated pattern ?

**Note** :

I asked similar question in SO, but my post was not precisely stated (old post was deleted). Here I come up with brand new correction. Thanks for help

Here is my external data set in my packages, list of csv files in extdata :

```
myPkg
 - inst
     - extdata
             - wgEncodeOpenChromChipK562CmycAlnRep1.csv
             - wgEncodeOpenChromChipK562CmycAlnRep2.csv
             - wgEncodeOpenChromChipK562CmycAlnRep3.csv
             - wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIfna6hStdAlnRep1.csv
             - wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIfna6hStdAlnRep2.csv
             - wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIfna30StdAlnRep1.csv
             - wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIfna30StdAlnRep2.csv
             - wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIfng6hStdAlnRep1.csv
             - wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIfng6hStdAlnRep2.csv
             - wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIggrabAlnRep1.csv
             - wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIggrabAlnRep2.csv
             - wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycStdAlnRep1.csv
             - wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycStdAlnRep2.csv
 - R
```

I intend to use system.file() to load my external data for my package use in package vignette code. because "wgEncode" pattern appeared in all csv files.

my desired output: all csv files in `inst/extdata` must be detected by system.file() and printed to console (or stored in object) :

**output** :

```
wgEncodeOpenChromChipK562CmycAlnRep1.csv
wgEncodeOpenChromChipK562CmycAlnRep2.csv
wgEncodeOpenChromChipK562CmycAlnRep3.csv
wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIfna6hStdAlnRep1.csv
wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIfna6hStdAlnRep2.csv
wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIfna30StdAlnRep1.csv
wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIfna30StdAlnRep2.csv
wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIfng6hStdAlnRep1.csv
wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIfng6hStdAlnRep2.csv
wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIggrabAlnRep1.csv
wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycIggrabAlnRep2.csv
wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycStdAlnRep1.csv
wgEncodeSydhTfbsK562CmycStdAlnRep2.csv
```

or :

```
csvFile <- print(getExtDat)
```

How can I achieve my desired output ? Any way to fix up my function to capture all csv files by using `system.file()` into console ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It seems `list.files(system.file('extdata', package = 'package_name'), recursive = TRUE)` is what you need.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I tried this one, but error comes up : object not found.

Comment: What is the output of `system.file('extdata', package = 'package_name')`? This should be a full path to a directory on the harddrive where your package is installed.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra my output is all csv files are printed out or stored in object in current R session. I think do bit more changes on my function could give me output. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
allfiles <- list.files(system.file(package = 'package_name'), 
                       recursive = TRUE)
CSVfiles  <- allfiles[grep("inst/extdata/+.*csv", allfiles)]
CSVfiles
```

Comment: sorry, this is not what I expected.